# How to change multiple FK to their own value/name on SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row in 'Task' table that contain 'AssignTo' column and 'AssignFrom' column. That column is relate with 'Employee' table. In 'Employee' table i have 'Name' column. How to query the 'Task' table with getting employee name ? I know about join but that just refer one column each table.

edit:
PK from 'Employee' table is OID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join could be performed multiple times:

```
SELECT t.*, e1.Name AS AssignFromTo, e2.Name AS AssignFromName
FROM Task t
JOIN Employee e1 
  ON t.AssignTo = e1.EmployeeId
JOIN Employee e2
  ON t.AssignFrom = e2.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins:

```
select t.*, ef.name as from_name, et.name as to_name
from task t left join
     employee ef
     on t.assignfrom = ef.name left join
     employee et
     on t.assignto = et.name;
```

This uses `left join` so no rows are lost if the assignment fields are empty.

Also, you should be using employee ids rather than names for the joins.  Perhaps you should revisit your data model.